# record soundcard with arecord (not microphone)

Tags: sound, audio-recording

I'm trying to record what my soundcard is sending to my speakers (from the command line), so I've read [HOWTO: Recording audio from the command line](http://jordilin.wordpress.com/2006/07/28/howto-recording-audio-from-the-command-line/)

However, when I do:

```
arecord -f cd -t raw | lame -r - testing.mp3
```

the **microphone** is recorded, not the sound that's going to my speakers.

How can I specify that I want the '**internal**' and not the microphone sound?